# Sync Linux's directory to Windows continuously

Tags: linux, windows, nfs, rsync, dropbox

Currently I am syncing a Linux directory to Windows folder via Dropbox.

However, I want to pursue an opensource alternative to this approach since I don't want to files on Dropbox server.

Are there any similar tools or approach I can use to do the sync in low latency fashion (beside Rsync?)

Answer (score 0):

An option that you can explore is to script it to copy the files or directory you want. You can then schedule it as a cron job to automate the process for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something similar to dropbox you can setup a owncloud Server. It's open source and works the same way.
Have a look here https://owncloud.org/